# Canvas Script Not Working

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm using this script on Wordpress and it works fine. However, I've decided to switch to Blogger instead. Now when I include it in the Blogger template, it doesn't work and I get this error in the Chrome console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Here is the script:

```
<script>
                <![CDATA[
!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!
function(d, w){
    var FPS = 30;//FPS
    var F = 300;//焦点距離
    var N = 3;//軌跡の本数
    var VERTEX_MAX = 10;//軌跡の長さ
    var TRAIL_QUALITY = 4000;//軌跡のクオリティ
    var mu = 0.5;//前のアンカーポイントへの依存具合
    var bmRandom = function(mu, sigma){
        var x, y, r, tmp=null, tmp2;
        return function(){
            if(tmp !== null){
                tmp2 = tmp;
                tmp = null;
                return y*tmp2+mu;
            }
            do{
                x = Math.random()*2-1;
                y = Math.random()*2-1;
                r = x*x+y*y;
            }while(r>=1);
            tmp = sigma*Math.sqrt(-2*Math.log(r)/r);
            return x*tmp+mu;
        };
    };
    pointCopy = function(src, dst){
        dst.x = src.x;
        dst.y = src.y;
        dst.z = src.z;
        return dst;
    };
    Trail = function(pos, t, color_f){
        this.pos={x:0,y:0,z:0};
        this.start={x:0,y:0,z:0};
        this.goal={x:0,y:0,z:0};
        this.anchor_1={x:0,y:0,z:0};
        this.anchor_2={x:0,y:0,z:0};
        this.start_time = 0;
        this.take_time = 1;
        this.vertexes = [];
        this.anchors_1 = [];
        this.anchors_2 = [];
        this.color_f = color_f;
        pointCopy(pos, this.pos);
        pointCopy(pos, this.start);
        pointCopy(pos, this.goal);
        this.setNextGoal(t);
    };
    Trail.prototype.setNextGoal = function(t, target){
        pointCopy(this.goal, this.start);
        this.anchor_1.x = this.start.x+(this.start.x-this.anchor_2.x)*mu;
        this.anchor_1.y = this.start.y+(this.start.y-this.anchor_2.y)*mu;
        this.anchor_1.z = this.start.z+(this.start.z-this.anchor_2.z)*mu;
        if(target){
            this.anchor_2.x = (this.anchor_1.x+target.x)/2+myrand();
            this.anchor_2.y = (this.anchor_1.y+target.y)/2+myrand();
            this.anchor_2.z = (this.anchor_1.z+target.z)/2+myrand();
            this.goal.x = target.x;
            this.goal.y = target.y;
            this.goal.z = target.z;
        }else{
            this.anchor_2.x = this.anchor_1.x+myrand();
            this.anchor_2.y = this.anchor_1.y+myrand();
            this.anchor_2.z = this.anchor_1.z+myrand();
            this.goal.x = this.anchor_2.x+myrand();
            this.goal.y = this.anchor_2.y+myrand();
            this.goal.z = this.anchor_2.z+myrand();
        }
        this.start_time = t;
        this.take_time = 200+Math.random()*200;
        this.vertexes.push(pointCopy(this.start, {x:0,y:0,z:0}));
        this.anchors_1.push(pointCopy(this.anchor_1, {x:0,y:0,z:0}));
        this.anchors_2.push(pointCopy(this.anchor_2, {x:0,y:0,z:0}));
        if(this.vertexes.length > VERTEX_MAX){
            this.vertexes.splice(0,this.vertexes.length-VERTEX_MAX);
            this.anchors_1.splice(0,this.anchors_1.length-VERTEX_MAX);
            this.anchors_2.splice(0,this.anchors_2.length-VERTEX_MAX);
        }
    };
    Trail.prototype.update = function(t, target){
        bezier3(
            t-this.start_time,
            this.start,
            this.anchor_1,
            this.anchor_2,
            this.goal,
            this.take_time,
            this.pos
            );
        if(t-this.start_time > this.take_time){
            this.setNextGoal(this.start_time+this.take_time, target);
            this.update(t, target);
        }
    };
    Trail.prototype.draw = function(ctx, camera, t){
        var i, dz, dt, ddt, rt, a, v={x:0, y:0, z:0};
        var ps = {x:0, y:0};
        ctx.beginPath();
        if(perspective(this.vertexes[0], camera, ps)){
            ctx.moveTo(ps.x, ps.y);
        }
        var x0 = ps.x;
        rt = (t-this.start_time)/this.take_time;
        for(i=1; i<this.vertexes.length; i++){
            ddt = 0.01;
            for(dt=0; dt<1; dt+=ddt){
                bezier3(dt,
                        this.vertexes[i-1],
                        this.anchors_1[i-1],
                        this.anchors_2[i-1],
                        this.vertexes[i],
                        1,
                        v);
                if(perspective(v, camera, ps)){
                    dz = v.z-camera.z;
                    a = 1-(this.vertexes.length-i+1-dt+rt)/VERTEX_MAX;
                    this.color_f(ctx, a, dz);
                    ctx.lineTo(ps.x, ps.y);
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(ps.x, ps.y);
                    ddt = dz/TRAIL_QUALITY+0.01;
                }
            }
        }
        ddt = 0.01;
        for(dt=0; dt<rt; dt+=ddt){
            bezier3(dt,
                    this.start,
                    this.anchor_1,
                    this.anchor_2,
                    this.goal,
                    1,
                    v);
            if(perspective(v, camera, ps)){
                dz = v.z-camera.z;
                a = 1-(1-dt+rt)/VERTEX_MAX;
                this.color_f(ctx, a, dz);
                ctx.lineTo(ps.x, ps.y);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(ps.x, ps.y);
                ddt = dz/TRAIL_QUALITY+0.01;
            }
        }
        if(perspective(this.pos, camera, ps)){
            dz = this.pos.z-camera.z;
            a = 1-1/VERTEX_MAX;
            this.color_f(ctx, a, dz);
            ctx.lineTo(ps.x, ps.y);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    };
    bezier3 = function(t, a, b, c, d, e, dst){
        t /= e;
        dst.x = 
            a.x*(1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            b.x*3*t*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            c.x*3*t*t*(1-t)+
            d.x*t*t*t;
        dst.y = 
            a.y*(1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            b.y*3*t*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            c.y*3*t*t*(1-t)+
            d.y*t*t*t;
        dst.z = 
            a.z*(1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            b.z*3*t*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            c.z*3*t*t*(1-t)+
            d.z*t*t*t;
    };
    perspective = function(point, camera, dst){
        var dx = point.x-camera.x;
        var dy = point.y-camera.y;
        var dz = point.z-camera.z;
        if(dz > 0){
            dst.x = F*dx/dz;
            dst.y = F*dy/dz;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
    updateScene = function(ctx){
        var i, goal;
        time_now = new Date().getTime();
        var time_d = time_now-time_pre;
        trails[0].update(time_now);
        for(i=1; i<trails.length; i++){
            trails[i].update(time_now, trails[i-1].pos);
        }
        camera.x += (trails[0].pos.x-camera.x)*0.0005*time_d;
        camera.y += (trails[0].pos.y-camera.y)*0.0005*time_d;
        camera.z += (trails[0].pos.z-camera.z-100)*0.0005*time_d;
        time_pre = time_now;
    };
    drawScene = function(ctx){
        var i;
        ctx.clearRect(-canvas.width/2, -canvas.height/2, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for(i=0; i<trails.length; i++){
            trails[i].draw(ctx, camera, time_now);
        }
    };
    var myrand = bmRandom(0,20);
    var canvas = d.getElementById("canvas-header");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var trails = [];
    var i;
    var time_now = new Date().getTime();
    var time_pre = time_now;
    var camera = {x:0, y:0, z:-200};
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        trails.push(new Trail({x:myrand(), y:myrand(), z:myrand()},
                              time_now,
                              function(a,z){return "#FFFFFF";}));
    }
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        switch(i%3){
            case 0:
                trails[i].color_f=function(ctx, a, dz){
                    var b = dz<10?0:a*F/dz;
                    b = (b>1?1:b)*(dz<30?(dz-10)/20:1);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255,"+Math.floor(255*a)+",0,"+b+")";
                    ctx.lineWidth = F/dz;
                    ctx.lineCap = b>0.8?"round":"butt";
                };
                break;
            case 1:
                trails[i].color_f=function(ctx, a, dz){
                    var b = dz<10?0:a*F/dz;
                    b = (b>1?1:b)*(dz<30?(dz-10)/20:1);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 255,"+Math.floor(255*a)+","+b+")";
                    ctx.lineWidth = F/dz;
                    ctx.lineCap = b>0.8?"round":"butt";
                };
                break;
            default:
                trails[i].color_f=function(ctx, a, dz){
                    var b = dz<10?0:a*F/dz;
                    b = (b>1?1:b)*(dz<30?(dz-10)/20:1);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba("+Math.floor(255*a)+",0,255,"+b+")";
                    ctx.lineWidth = F/dz;
                    ctx.lineCap = b>0.8?"round":"butt";
                };
                break;
        }
    }
    canvas.width = w.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = w.innerHeight;
    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
    setInterval(function(){
        updateScene();
        drawScene(ctx);
    }, 1000/FPS);
}(document, window);
]]>
</script>
```

Since the Blogger template is XML, I had to add the CDATA tags. Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT: This is the error I get when I don't use CDATA:

> Error parsing XML, line 2101, column 40: Element type
>   "this.vertexes.length" must be followed by either attribute
>   specifications, ">" or "/>"

With syntax highlighting, the problem is somewhere around this bit:

```
var x0 = ps.x;
        rt = (t-this.start_time)/this.take_time;
        for(i=1; i<this.vertexes.length; i++){
            ddt = 0.01;
            for(dt=0; dt<1; dt+=ddt){
                bezier3(dt,
                        this.vertexes[i-1],
                        this.anchors_1[i-1],
                        this.anchors_2[i-1],
                        this.vertexes[i],
                        1,
                        v);
                if(perspective(v, camera, ps)){
                    dz = v.z-camera.z;
                    a = 1-(this.vertexes.length-i+1-dt+rt)/VERTEX_MAX;
                    this.color_f(ctx, a, dz);
                    ctx.lineTo(ps.x, ps.y);
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(ps.x, ps.y);
                    ddt = dz/TRAIL_QUALITY+0.01;
                }
            }
        }
        ddt = 0.01;
        for(dt=0; dt<rt; dt+=ddt){
            bezier3(dt,
                    this.start,
                    this.anchor_1,
                    this.anchor_2,
                    this.goal,
                    1,
                    v);
            if(perspective(v, camera, ps)){
                dz = v.z-camera.z;
                a = 1-(1-dt+rt)/VERTEX_MAX;
                this.color_f(ctx, a, dz);
                ctx.lineTo(ps.x, ps.y);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(ps.x, ps.y);
                ddt = dz/TRAIL_QUALITY+0.01;
            }
        }
        if(perspective(this.pos, camera, ps)){
            dz = this.pos.z-camera.z;
            a = 1-1/VERTEX_MAX;
            this.color_f(ctx, a, dz);
            ctx.lineTo(ps.x, ps.y);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    };
    bezier3 = function(t, a, b, c, d, e, dst){
        t /= e;
        dst.x = 
            a.x*(1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            b.x*3*t*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            c.x*3*t*t*(1-t)+
            d.x*t*t*t;
        dst.y = 
            a.y*(1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            b.y*3*t*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            c.y*3*t*t*(1-t)+
            d.y*t*t*t;
        dst.z = 
            a.z*(1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            b.z*3*t*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            c.z*3*t*t*(1-t)+
            d.z*t*t*t;
    };
    perspective = function(point, camera, dst){
        var dx = point.x-camera.x;
        var dy = point.y-camera.y;
        var dz = point.z-camera.z;
        if(dz > 0){
            dst.x = F*dx/dz;
            dst.y = F*dy/dz;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
```

Which I kinda understand the issue now, but don't know how to fix it. Blogger is reading that as a beginning tag, rather than a less than statement.

Comment: Where are the CDATA tags? Which line does the error point to? What's with the !+-+-+! stuff?

Comment: I omitted the CDATA Tags because it wasn't in the original script.

Comment: When you click on the location to the right of the error message, what line does it highlight?

Comment: You omitted the CDATA tags from the actual Blogger script, or just from the question? You should really post what you *actually* have.

Comment: @Juhana: The `!+-+-+!` stuff is a bunch of prefix operators stuck together. They serve to alert the JavaScript parser that the function it's going to be parsing is a function expression, not a function definition. Really, just one `!`, `~`, `+`, or `-` would have sufficed, but I guess the `!+-+-+!` stuff looks kind of like a header.

Comment: @icktoofay since the Blogger template is XML with conditional statements, the line referenced is completely unreliable. It saYS LINE 1974, is nothing but HTML, including surrounding lines. '     <div class='content-fauxcolumns'>
        <div class='fauxcolumn-outer content-fauxcolumn-outer'>
          <div class='cap-top'>
            <div class='cap-left'/>
            <div class='cap-right'/>
          </div>
          <div class='fauxborder-left'>
            <div class='fauxborder-right'/>
            <div class='fauxcolumn-inner'>
            </div>'

Comment: @Xarcell: When you click on it in the console, though, it should highlight the line after it has been processed by Blogger and you should be able to see the content of that line, even if the line number does not correspond to the line number of your template. It would be helpful to know what that line was.

Comment: @Juhana I edited it to what I added what I ACTUALLY have. I wasn't sure if the CDATA tags were even proper.

Comment: @icktoofay I'm just not seeing what your trying to tell me. I don't see anything highlighted.

Comment: @icktoofay http://xarpixels.blogspot.com/

Comment: @Xarcell: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FAnuQ.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/0UQ9i.png

Comment: 'window["_gaUserPrefs"] = { ioo : function() { return true; } }' which is not found anywhere in my template.

Comment: Are you really sure you need the CDATA tags? The doctype is HTML5 and none of the other scripts are wrapped in CDATA.

Comment: @Juhana this is why i didn't include them in the initial post.

Comment: updated post with error without CDATA

Comment: Can't you just put the CDATA tags _outside_ the `<script>` tags?

Comment: I hate when people vote to close a question they can't answer or just don't like. Instead of letting people help. Anyways, I managed to solve the problem thanks to everyone's input here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I realized, just as Juhana said, I don't need the CDATA tags. From there I realized that Blogger was taking less than less than symbols and thinking they were opening tags. So All I did was change the `<` enities to `&#60;`. That resolved the problem...

Thanks to @Juhana and @icktoofay for helping me resolve the issue, instead of ignoring or voting to close the topic.